# Did any or many conservative news outlets report on the new IPCC climate change report today?

Tags: media, climate-change

I read stories today about the International Panel on Climate Change, the IPCC, releasing their conclusions of a three-year-long report. It states that by 2030 we will have reached their set safety threshold of a 1.5 degrees Celsius average temperature rise since pre-industrial times. According to the report the 1.5 degree threshold (or above) is the point at which potentially irreversible damage will be done to the Earth's ecosystems. The report also states that our levels of CO2 will have to drop by 45% by 2030. As things currently stand we are not on target to meet the CO2 emissions reduction, and will possibly be overshooting the 1.5 degree warming threshold into the future past 2030. It states that only unprecedented levels of efforts will have to be devoted to this task in order to meet these goals.

It has appeared rather visibly on the main/front page of many news media sites. I know that a general attitude among many is that the news media is generally liberal/left leaning, so I checked news sites generally reputed to be conservative leaning, such as Fox News, and I didn't find this reported on. I can give links of the stories I found, what I'd like to know is whether many perceived conservative news media outlets have reported this story. I'd be really interested if anyone has come across this story on what would be called more "conservative" news outlets. The following are all front/main page stories.

> Planet has only until 2030 to stop climate change
>   [CNN](http://Planet%20has%20only%20until%202030%20to%20stop%20climate%20change)
>
> Final call to save the world from 'climate catastrophe'
>   [BBC](http://Final%20call%20to%20save%20the%20world%20from%20'climate%20catastrophe')
>
> 'Some sort of report' Australian government backs coal in defiance of
>   IPCC climate warning.
>  [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2018/oct/09/australian-government-backs-coal-defiance-ipcc-climate-warning)
>
> World leaders 'have moral obligation to act' after UN climate report 
>   [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2018/oct/08/world-leaders-have-moral-obligation-to-act-after-un-climate-report)
>
> Dire Climate Warning Lands With a Thud on Trump’s Desk 
> [New York
>   Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/08/us/politics/climate-change-united-nations-trump.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage)
>
> New UN Climate Report Dims Hope For Averting Catastrophic Global Warming
>   [Huffington Post](http://New%20UN%20Climate%20Report%20Dims%20Hope%20For%20Averting%20Catastrophic%20Global%20Warming)
>
> Scientists: Time running short before climate change effects are 'irreversible' 
>   [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/International/united-nations-report-details-looming-climate-crisis/story?id=58354235&cid=clicksource_4380645_1_hero_headlines_headlines_hed)

Supposedly conservative news outlets:

> [Fox News](https://www.foxnews.com/): Credit to James K for saying that Fox News did run a story on it, in the science section.
>
> [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html): Credit to "user" for pointing out that the Daily Mail did run a story on it, it is in the science and tech section. The link is in the comment to their answer.
>
> [Breitbart](https://www.breitbart.com/) Not anywhere on main page
>
> [NewsMax](https://www.newsmax.com/) Not anywhere on main page
>
> WorldNetDaily: The clock is ticking to stop catastrophic global warming, top climate
>   scientists say
>  [On front page of WorldNetDaily, but article links
>   to the Hartford Courant](http://www.courant.com/nation-world/hc-wp-climate-global-warming-report-20181008-story.html)

Comment: Comments deleted. Comments should be used to suggest improvements to the question, not argue about the subject matter of the question.

Comment: Also, none of the comments provided an explanation why this question is not about politics. We have allowed questions asking about media reporting about political topics in the past. And climate change is a politically relevant topic.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if this is off topic or not, but I changed my question by removing any trace of something that could be taken as non-neutral, certain phrases etc. At least I've tried to do so.

Comment: I think answering this question would basically be listing conservative outlets that did report on it. Given how many (conservative) news outlets there are, there are bound to be some that did report on it. I don't really see how making a list of those that did (or didn't) report would be about the scope of this SE. Of course climate change from a policy perspective is still relevant. Asking about why (specific) political parties / movements don't accept the contents of the IPCC report would certainly be relevant.

Comment: @JJJ That's fair enough, I accept that. The other thing I find interesting is that most (I think) had the story on the main page easily visible, whereas the two conservative ones we've identified have had it in the science or science and technology section, not on the main page. Also, as time goes on and new stories are published the question whether or not it will be "main/front page" will probably be impossible to answer. So I admit it's likely a bad question. I was just very curious about this. I'll probably delete the question soon.

Comment: @ Phillip I'd like to delete this question. The reason is even though I think it might be a valid question in the way I reformed it, it seems to be asking a question, namely about main page story content which changes daily, and so will be impossible to answer in the future. When I go to delete it I get a warning that since there's answers to the question it is not recommended for me to delete it, and that I may be barred from asking further questions in the future. I'm worried about being barred because I think this is a good place to get information. How many deletions before being barred?

Comment: @Philipp Actually the system won't let me delete this question. It gives the message: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

Answer (score 4):

Yes Fox news reported on it, using a reporter from New York Post (also generally considered a conservative news outlet)

https://www.foxnews.com/science/terrifying-climate-change-warning-12-years-until-were-doomed

Answer (score 1):

The Daily Mail [reported it in the UK](https://twitter.com/DMReporter/status/1049248914086481921). Warning: the comments are the usual Daily Mail standard.

Comment: The link to their article is here https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-6250839/UN-study-says-eating-meat-throwing-gas-boiler-stop-Earth-overheating.html?ns_mchannel=rss&ito=1490&ns_campaign=1490

Comment: Thanks @Zebrafish, but I prefer not to give them traffic.